# Bash script: How to replace text in package.json with sed

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I just wann  write a very basic script, which

- inits npm in a new project folder
- Installs nodemon
- creates an index.js file
- adds a start command into the package.json for nodemon
- writes "console.log" into the index.js file

I seem to be close, but adjusting the package.json does not work. Somehow the search variable is two time in ...

### I want to achive:

```
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon my_file.js"
```

### I achive:

```
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1""test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" exit 1","start": "nodemon my_file.js"
```

### Full code

```
#!/bin/bash -e
set -e
clear

# Init npm
npm init -y && npm i --save-dev nodemon && touch index.js

wait

# find test command
constToFind='\"test\": \"echo \\\"Error: no test specified\\\" && exit 1\"'

# add nodemon command (with comma, line break and tab)
replacement=',\n\t\"start\": \"nodemon my_file.js\"'
combineReplacement="${constToFind}${replacement}"

# Add start command to package.json
sed -i "s/$constToFind/$combineReplacement/g" package.json

# Create entry javascript file with console.clear on tops
echo "console.clear();" >> index.js
```

Comment: Do you _have to_ use sed? Why not use a different tool that cna parse json, like `jq`? Are you aware what `&` character means in `sed`s  `s` command replacement part? Maybe does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern solves your issue?

Comment: Not sure, I just used it yesterday, to adjust a .env file in another script and there it worked nice. Right now I just look for a simple tool, to adjust text in all kind of files, since I do not need to do that often.
But I keep that in mind, for the next time, if I need to work on a json.
Actually I am not aware, it just worked the last time, so it got my blue print. But I gonna check it out. – Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of substituting you can append with the sed `a` command:

```
$ addon='\"start\": \"nodemon my_file.js\"'
$ sed "/$constToFind/a\
$addon
" package.json
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon my_file.js"
```

(if you care your `package.json` file use the `-i` only after you checked that it really works as expected).

And if your `sed` version supports the alternate syntax this is a bit simpler:

```
$ addon='\"start\": \"nodemon my_file.js\"'
$ sed "/$constToFind/a$addon" package.json
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon my_file.js"
```

Comment: Awesome. That is way better then what I was trying.
Weird is, that you previous/unedited answer works well (# add nodemon command
addon=' ,"start\": \"nodemon my_file.js\"'

# Add start command to package.json
sed -ir "/$constToFind/a\
$addon
" package.json). But the updated, with and without -i or -ir or -r does not.
Anyway, it works. Thanks for that.

Comment: Ah! What version of `sed` do you use?

Comment: (sed --version results in: sed (GNU sed) 4.7

Comment: Mine is 4.8. It could be that. Or not (I don't have 4.7 installed here). Anyway, I restored the working answer and added the simpler one in case it is supported.